# CSS Grid not functioning properly despite validation services giving me the 100%?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

When running both my HTML and CSS through the validation services I was given the green light yet the code itself doesn't come out using the grid. This is the CSS in question:

```
body {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 6fr;
grid-template-rows: 6fr;
background-color: #f4fff4;
height: 500px;
}

.Background {
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 6;
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 6;
}

#Heads {
grid-row-start: 2;
grid-row-end: 2;
grid-column-start: 2;
grid-column-end: 5;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Backdrop {
grid-row-start: 3;
grid-row-end: 3;
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 6;
}

.Arrow {
grid-row-start: 3;
grid-row-end: 3;
grid-column-start: 6;
grid-column-end: 6;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Regis {
grid-row-start: 5;
grid-row-end: 5;
grid-column-start: 2;
grid-column-end: 3;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Cont {
grid-row-start: 5;
grid-row-end: 5;
grid-column-start: 4;
grid-column-end: 5;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Refer {
grid-row-start: 4;
grid-row-end: 4;
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: 4;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Website Domain Name</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="All in due time.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Git, Code, Win, Yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="Hit1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Background">
<header id="Heads">
  <h1>Click <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Here!</a></h1>
  <select>
    <option>Beans</option>
    <option>Cans</option>
    <option>Frijole</option>
    <option>Jaguar</option>
  </select>
  </header>
<div class="Backdrop">
  <div class="Arrow">
    <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com"><img src="Arrows.jpg" alt="Arrow"></a></p>
  </div>
<div class="Regis">
  <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Registration</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="Cont">
  <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Contact Us</a></p>
  </div>
<div class="Refer">
  <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">References</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any and all ideas or thoughts are appreciated. I'm writing at this point so that the post isn't entirely code. Tyvm! =]

Comment: how did you conform that the stylesheet is loading in the browser? Inspect and see if the classNames have css properties or not. I am asking you this question because I see your link tag in HTML stylesheet name is Hit1.css First letter in uppercase, probably a case you might consider to look at.

Comment: I opened the page through multiple browsers; the background color changed accordingly when I altered them.

Comment: As we do not know how your layout has to be? and I think you need little practice with grid as well. I see that you used display:grid on body alone. its better if you experiment some more your structure in codepen [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQJyZx#anon-login] I played around with your css a little. unable to replicate your problem.

Comment: And I would rather not use uppercase for the first letter for my classes and id.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried tweaking things a little. I would like to have the "click here" in the center (now text-align: center; but still not working) and the three bottom divs centered as well. Theoretically, the grid should put them in place from my column/row alignment, but it just doesn't seem to function. After studying a bit more CSS I now also know about calling through specific elements.

Comment: After researching a bit more CSS, I believe I have found the fix! Thank you very much for your time and help. Hope I can return the favor in time.

Answer (score -1):

```
.Background {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 6;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 6;
}
.Background div{
    display: grid;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21514022)

Comment: Do you have a try, you grid-xxx-xxx do not work, because display is not grid.